# Gstreamer video enc/dec is not working on imx nitrogen 6x

Tags: gstreamer, imx6

I am writing a GStreamer application for IMX nitrogen 6x to encode to h264, decode and render. This works fine with Gstreamer command mentioned below.

```
#gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! queue ! imxvpudec ! imx2dvideosink
```

But Gstreamer application code is not working. Facing below error:

*> > 0:00:00.229253000   245   0x9d1ee0 ERROR      imxeglplatform_fb egl_platform_fb.c:72:gst_imx_egl_viv_sink_egl_platform_create: eglGetDisplay failed: bad alloc*

Could readers pls help me.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#define CAPS "video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=160,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1"
#define CAPS "video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)2, profile=(string)high, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1"

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *sink, *dec_pipeline, *source;
  gint       width, height;
  GstSample  *sample;
  GstBuffer  *buf;
  gchar      *descr, *dec_descr;
  GError     *error = NULL;
  gint64     duration, position;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;
  gboolean   res;
  GstMapInfo map;
  gint       itr;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* create a new pipeline */
  descr =
     g_strdup_printf ("videotestsrc horizontal-speed=5 ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! tee name=t t. ! queue  ! appsink name=sink caps=\"" CAPS "\"");

  pipeline = gst_parse_launch (descr, &error);

  if (error != NULL) {
    g_print ("could not construct pipeline: %s\n", error->message);
    g_clear_error (&error);
    exit (-1);
  }

  dec_pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("appsrc name=source caps=\"" CAPS "\" ! queue ! imxvpudec ! imx2dvideosink", &error);
  if (error != NULL) {
    g_print ("could not construct decoder pipeline: %s\n", error->message);
    g_clear_error (&error);
    exit (-1);
  }

  /* get sink and source from respective pipeline*/
  sink   = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "sink");
  source = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (dec_pipeline), "source");
  if( !source ) {
     g_print("Get source from pipeline is failed");
  }

  /* set to PAUSED to make the first frame arrive in the sink */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
  switch (ret) {
    case GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE:
      g_print ("failed to play the file\n");
      exit (-1);
    case GST_STATE_CHANGE_NO_PREROLL:
      /* for live sources, we need to set the pipeline to PLAYING before we can
       * receive a buffer. We don't do that yet */
      g_print ("live sources not supported yet\n");
      exit (-1);
    default:
      break;
  }

  gst_element_set_state (dec_pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
  g_print ("dec pipeline moved to pause state successfully\n");


  /* This can block for up to 5 seconds. If your machine is really overloaded,
   * it might time out before the pipeline prerolled and we generate an error. A
   * better way is to run a mainloop and catch errors there. */
  ret = gst_element_get_state (pipeline, NULL, NULL, 5 * GST_SECOND);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_print ("failed to play the file\n");
    exit (-1);
  }

  ret    =  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  sample =  gst_app_sink_pull_preroll(GST_APP_SINK(sink));
  //handle_sample_buffer(sample);

  gst_element_set_state (dec_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  buf = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);

  g_print("Pushing buffer to app src\n");
  ret = gst_app_src_push_buffer(source, buf);
  if (ret == GST_FLOW_FLUSHING) {
      g_print ("appsrc is not paused\n");
  } else
  if (ret == GST_FLOW_EOS) {
      g_print("EOS occured\n");
  } else {
      g_print("Buffer is not queued successfully\n");
  }

  do {
      /* if we have a buffer now, convert it to a pixbuf. It's possible that we
       * don't have a buffer because we went EOS right away or had an error. */
       sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(GST_APP_SINK(sink));
       buf = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample); 
       //handle_sample_buffer(sample);
       ret = gst_app_src_push_buffer(source, buf);
     }while(1);

  /* cleanup and exit */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  gst_element_set_state (dec_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (dec_pipeline);

  exit (0);
}
```

Comment: hm try the gst-launch with tee, which line is 72?

Comment: oh thats not from your sources.. its [this](https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx/blob/master/src/eglvivsink/egl_platform_fb.c#L72) file and the error means you have no display "allocated"

Comment: why do you use appsrc and appsink - you can use tee to split the content into to processing branches and in one you display and in another you can have appsink where you would process your frame (if you need to - I do not know your use case)

Comment: @otopolsky: My use case is i get the h264 data from a remote device to imx device, rtp headers will be stripped off and my module gets raw h264 data which i need to play using hardware decoder on imx which is imxvpudec. Currently am using imx2dvideosink as the renderer in my decode pipeline which is giving the issue on imx device. I have tried with other elements (autovideosink, xvimagesink etc..) but facing same issue.

Comment: well I still do not see the reason to use the appsrc/appsink duo. Why dont you use rtp depayloaders which will get you the raw h264 data (aligned on au or nal)? The element is called rtph264depay